Algorithm to extract key points from line drawing
I have orthographic 3-view black and white line drawings like this:

I would like to extract a set of 'key points' from this kind of drawing.  By 'key point', I mean corners and a few points along each curve.  Enough information such that you could reasonably reconstruct the drawing by playing connect-the-dots, but still making a reasonable attempt to minimize the amount of data.
This is closely related to converting a raster image to a vector drawing.  That may in fact be the way to go.  However, the tools I've found for raster to vector conversion are typically huge overkill for my needs.  1) I don't actually need vector output, I just want the key points.  2) many of these seem tailored to solid color images, building polygons to flood areas -- and they do not seem well suited for line drawings.
If a line in the drawing is typically 4-pixels wide, I would like to extract key points down the center of that line.  I do not want to detect the line as a skinney polygon.
What algorithms are well suited to this problem?  I would hope to find a simple solution that isn't too onerous to implement myself.  Otherwise, an open source library in C++ (non-GPL) would be ideal -- this is for an open source project, but with a non-GPL license.
Ultimately, the plane for each 2D image will be located and oriented in 3D space.  The 2D key points will then be converted into a 3D cloud of points which will act as a guide to help reconstruct a 3D model.  This will obviously be far from perfect, but imagine it as a tool to help accelerate building a 3D model in something like Blender.
